# MySQL multiple data in one cell

Tags: php, mysql, select

So my problem is that I want to select rows where `league_id` is equal to something, but I want to store multiple values in one cell.

[image: mysqltable]
So this is may tabel and as you can see, I have two values in one cell.

I want to select rwo from DB where `league_id` is equal 2.

Comment: My suggestion is to make another table that will connect id with league_id, one row for each league_id.

Comment: Storing multiple values in one "cell" is almost never a good idea, precisely because it's hard to search on data in that "cell", and will never be quick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *best* way would be to normalize this data and store the leagues in a separate table, but if you are not able or willing to do that, you can use the [`FIND_IN_SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function in MySQL.

```
SELECT * 
FROM YourTable t 
WHERE 
  FIND_IN_SET('2', t.league_id) > 0
```

Comment: For The best Way u_u +1

Comment: I already have a table with leagues, but i want to select one result where league_id is equal 2, but still have multiple values of league_id for each team. It's like FC Barcelona is playing in spanish league(league_id=2) and champions league(league_id=1) at the same time.

Comment: I meant a junction table (or cross table) that stores the relationship between a club and a league. Each club and each league exist only once in their respective tables, but in the junction table you can link multiple clubs to multiple leagues. Basic rule of thumb: if you have a relationship between two tables and you can't create a foreign key for it, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Ok I think I will make another table where I can connect two other tables ;) thanks for your help guys ;)